# Code base architecture for one app that has multiple versions with small changes

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I'm building a hybrid mobile app that has slightly different versions but share 99.9% of the code. There is a paid and free version, which differ in one function only. Also there is a slight difference between the iPhone and Android versions.

I have the code in a git repository but I don't want to replicate the repo 4 times and work on changes to the code 4 times, makes no sense.

So I'm looking for a way of having "sub-repos" that could share most of the code and could be easily switched to have the custom parts overridden.
Any ideas what should I use?

Comment: Why not have the differences be data driven and determine which data set you load based on the version?  That way you could easily have people upgrade from the free version to the paid version in app instead of having 2 versions on the app store.

Comment: I agree 99% same code sounds like using configurations is a better approach.